# SAP Logic App connector - unexpected SAPfilters behaviour when receiving Messages

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm getting a lot of problems with receiving SAP IDocs in Logic Apps (coming via an onprem gateway).
I think the problem is the use of `SAPAction` filters. We have different logic apps to process different message types but they all use the same GatewayService and ProgramId.

[image: Logic App to receive material changes]

My hope was that the `SapActions` filter would ignore and not process/dequeue messages outside the filter, allowing another logic app with the right filter to pick them up instead.

Seems to not work like this as a few messages come through and most never get out of the gateway - there is a warning in the gateway log that "message will be rejected":

> SapAdapter20231120.000000001.log:11/21/2023 3:30:16 PM
> EventName=LegacyTraceWarning Level=Warning ProcessID=4588 ThreadID=704
> sourceId=Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SapInboundRequestHandler/53394281
> correlationCode=InboundCall  shortMessage=InboundContract.TryReceive.
> IDOC inbound, action filter is present and this IDOC
> 'http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Idoc/3/ZMATMAS04//756/Receive'
> is not allowed per the filter. Message will be rejected.

I read somewhere that the "receive message" connector is a webhook behaviour rather than long-polling - but there is so little documentation on this that I really can't see how it works.

My question is how do I use SAPAction filters correctly?

Also is there any documentation anywhere on this?